# Smartface IDE can not load a project

Tags: smartface.io

While reopening a saved project I get the following error: "Error on loading the project. Can not open project. Project file is corrupted. DataTable with the following GUID is missing: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-100000000001".

Comp rebooting doesn't help.

When inspecting sfpx-file and files in _data folder I see no signs of corruption. Is there any way to restore the project file without building the app from scratch?

Comment: Did you get any error while savving the project ?

Comment: No...............................

Comment: I localized the problem. There is a dataset in my app which is described in Datasets\DS_AvgPrice.dts. The dataset is build on the following select: SELECT "L"."LabName", Sum("TM"."Price" * "MT"."Weight") AS "AvgPrice" FROM "Lab" AS "L", "MedTest" AS "MT", "TestMapping" AS "TM" WHERE "L"."LabID" = "MT"."LabID" AND "MT"."MedTestID" = "TM"."MedTestID" GROUP BY "L"."LabName" ORDER BY "AvgPrice"

Comment: When the dataset is saved (without any error) in the dts-file:<br>... <OBJECT>
   <Fields>
    <Field ID="2" Name="Lab.LabName" ...
    <Field ID="-1" Name=".LabName" ....
   </Fields>
   <SqlText>
   <![CDATA[
SELECT "L"."LabName", Sum("TM"."Price" * "MT"."Weight") AS "AvgPrice" FROM "Lab" AS "L", "MedTest" AS "MT", "TestMapping" AS "TM" WHERE "L"."LabID" = "MT"."LabID" AND "MT"."MedTestID" = "TM"."MedTestID" GROUP BY "L"."LabName" ORDER BY "AvgPrice"
   ]]>
   </SqlText>
  </TypeSpecific>
 </Dataset>
</OBJECT>
<br>. The string <Field ID="-1" Name=".LabName"... looks suspicious.

Comment: If I delete the string - the project could be open without any errors. I go to the dataset within IDE and save it again (no errors).  Then try to open the project and here comes the error again. It seems the problem has something to do with SELECT using aggregate functions.

Comment: Is it possible to share the project ?

Comment: I can send it to an e-mail. Is that ok? or I should share it in a different way?